# CodeIgniter error when connecting to any database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I just downloaded a fresh copy of CI from their site(version 3.0.3) and simply configured database and loaded it, but i am having error.

Below is my database configuration in config.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'shortagesdb',
'dbdriver' => 'mysql',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,//(ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

and here is what i am doing in my controller i-e simply loading database

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

Nothing fancy here and i am getting this exception no matter what

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in D:\Projects\ims\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php on line 136
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: change `'dbdriver' => 'mysql'` to `'dbdriver' => 'mysqli'`

Comment: but i am using mysql or mssql, why should i use mysqli ?

Comment: mysqli means mysql inproved. So, nothing to worry.

Comment: ahh got, you, let me try

Comment: @ChetanAmeta did what you asked and got this error again `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in D:\Projects\ims\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php on line 125`

Comment: What localhost you using "wamp, xampp, lamp" etc.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 it's wamp

Answer (score 3):

> **Codeigniter 3 won't support MySQL. [MySQL is deprecated in version 3.0](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#database-drivers-mysql-sqlite-mssql-pdo-dblib)**

Try this

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root', # check username
'password' => '', # check password
'database' => 'shortagesdb', # check DB name is correct
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli', # remove mysql
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'), # remove TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

[image]

Comment: the usename and password is correct. What if i want to use mssql server ? i get the same error

Comment: you cant use `mysql` in CI 3.

Comment: what do i need to do, if i  want to use mssql server ?

Comment: no you cant. Or use CI 2. ***MySQLi* is improved security of *MySQL***

Comment: i have done what you suggested above, now having this error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in D:\Projects\ims\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php on line 125`

Comment: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in D:\Projects\ims\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in your php.ini file, go to you php folder and open that file in a text editor. Now find the extensions and uncomment this:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Also check that you extension path is correctly directed to your ext folder in the php root location.

Comment: if are you using php7 make sure you using the php.ini of php 7. /etc/php/7.0/cli