# The error comes when I host my project done in codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting

My project worked in localhost, but showing error on server:

[image: Error]

Comment: check for white space before php tag or some output is generating before exicuting code

Comment: Look at the fatal error first. Figure out why `mysqli` failed.

Comment: It could be your hosting does not support the whole functionalities of the Database Drtiver you can head to **Application/config/database.php** and change these line from ` 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',` to `'dbdriver' => 'pdo',`

Comment: it would be nice if you post your database.php and also go to `Application/Logs` and open the log dated today additional error information may be in the file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root', # check username
'password' => '', # check password
'database' => 'shortagesdb', # check DB name is correct
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli', # remove mysql
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'), # remove TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

or may be

It is not a bug in your application, it is just a missing driver, so, you have couple of options...

Go to your php init and uncomment the following:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

If not, try installing it at your server, it varies depending on your distribution.

Try installing  php5-mysqlnd

If you cannot do it by hosting restrictions then just move to mysql driver (wont need to change other configurations or queries in CodeIgniter or anything else...)

like this (at your config file)

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'; (you might have mysqli now)
```

source [Codeigniter: fatal error call to undefined function mysqli_init()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612956/codeigniter-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-init) and [CodeIgniter error when connecting to any database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852683/codeigniter-error-when-connecting-to-any-database)

Comment: how we change the php.ini config in godaddy

Comment: they told that this is a virtual server so they are not able to provide a tech support

Comment: check this link might be help full to you http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=540760

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/medmaacom/public_html/application/models/User_model.php:167)

Comment: there was no problem in localhost,but in server this error comes

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php